# Heine-Borel proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Prove the Heine-Borel Theorem: A set $K \subseteq \mathbb R$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb R$ if and only if every open cover of $K$ has a finite sub-cover.

**My attempt**

First assume that $K$ is closed and bounded. Consider an open cover $\{C_i\}$ of $K$: $K \subseteq \cup_i C_i$ where the $C_i$ are open sets. Note that $K \setminus \cup^n_iC_i $ is closed for all $n$ since $\cup^n_iC_i $ is open.

Seeking a contradiction, assume that no finite subcover of $\{C_i\}$ exists. *In this case, $K \setminus \cup^n_iC_i $ is non-empty (contains at least one element) for all $n$. So we have that: $\lim_n |K \setminus \cup^n_i C_i| > 0$ (by monotone convergence). But this is a contradiction since $C_i$ is a cover: $K \subseteq \lim_n \cup^n_iC_i $. So every open cover of $K$ must have a finite subcover.

Next assume that every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover. Let $x$ be a limit point of $K$. Let $a_i$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $a_i \rightarrow x$.

Seeking a contradiction, assume that $x \notin K$, so that $K$ is not closed. Take any open cover $\{C_i\}$ of $K$ and define $D_i = (\cup_i C_i) \setminus N_{1/i}(x)$ which is also an open cover of $K$ (where $N_\delta(x)$ is a closed neighborhood of size $\delta$ around $x$). So, for each finite $n$ there exists an element of the sequence $a_i$ close enough to $x$ that is not in the set $\cup_i^n D_i$. So no finite subcover exists**. This is a contradiction, so $K$ must be closed.

Similarly, $K$ must be bounded. Seeking a contradiction, assume it is not. Let $a_i$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $a_i \rightarrow \infty$. Given an open cover of $K$ we can define another cover $G_j = (\cup_i C_i \ \{a_i\}_i^\infty) \cup \{a_i\}_i^j$ (which includes all the points of $a_i$ up until the $j$th element). But for every finite $n$ there exists an element of the sequence $a_i$ large enough that is not an element of $\cup^n_iD_i$. So no finite subcover exists, which is a contradiction, so $K$ must be bounded.

**My question**

Have I missed anything or made any incorrect reasoning?

I'm concerned that the point marked by * is equivalent to assuming the set is open and needs further justification.

The assumption at the point marked by ** is that the set of finite subcovers is the same as the set of subcovers defined by finite $n$. I'm pretty sure this is true since it doesn't matter how you order the covering sets.

Comment: Some fast advice, others may be more helpful.  (i) Don't try to use measure theory for this one.  (ii)  To show compact must be bounded.  Given any unbounded set,  *you* supply a cover [you are instead saying "given a cover"--wrong method].  (iii)  To show compact must be closed.  Given any set that is not closed *you* supply a cover [you are instead saying "given a cover"--again wrong method].

Comment: i) do you mean the claim that the set is non-empty is incorrect? (the point *)
ii and iii) but I want to show that the claim is true for any cover, rather than just one that I specify. @B.S.Thomson

Comment: The measure theory didn't work.  Here is how to show unbounded sets are not compact.  If $E$ is unbounded consider the family of all intervals $(n,n+2)$ for $n=0, \pm1, \pm 2, \dots.$  Explain why there is no finite subfamily that covers $E$.  Here is how to show that sets that are not closed cannot be compact.  Suppose that $x_0$ is a limit point of a set $E$ but $x_0\not\in E$.  Consider the family of all intervals $(-\infty, x_0-\frac1n)$ and $(x_0 + \frac1n,\infty)$.  Show this is an open cover but no finite collection forms a subcover.  See--you get to specify!

Comment: My preference is to use $U_n= \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid \vert x \vert \lt n \}$ to show that a compact set must be bounded and to use $V_n(x_0)= \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid \vert x - x_0 \vert \gt \frac 1n \}$ to show that a compact set must be closed.